# How to set Permissions and Content Security Policy for Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, manifest, content-security-policy

I'm trying to get my Chrome extension approved and want to understand how I should properly fill in the "permissions" and "csp" sections of the manifest.json. Those parts looks as follows:

```
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather*"
  ],

  "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather*; script-src 'self'"
  ...
```

And that got rejected.

I'm using only:

1. localStorage to store info about weather;
2. Openweathermap API to get weather info (JSON).

I don't use any remote scripts.

So, my questions are:

1. Do I really need a "storage" string if I use localStorage (not a chrome.storage)?
2. What is a proper way to set a CSP in my case?